# Add specific scala file to the build.sbt not all the directory it is in

Tags: scala, sbt

so I have a git sub-module that I want to include some Scala files from in my project but I don't want to include the a whole directory just some specific Scala files who to change the following line or what to add in order to include some specific Scala files to the build.sbt

```
  unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile ++=  addons.value.map(baseDirectory.value / _ /"")
```

Comment: Why can't you include directory and use specific files from the directory? Could you put specific files to some package and include the directory of this package?

Comment: I am just using a git submodule so it isn't my code and I can't change it's hierarchy, and it isn't the best approach for me to edit the sub-module myself
and some scala files of this submodule will make a compilation error 
so I don't want to include them

Answer (score 0):

Remove command `unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile ++= ...` **and** add command

```
sources in Compile ++= Seq("SpecificFile1.scala", "SpecificFile2.scala")
  .map(baseDirectory.value / "external_directory" / _)
```

if you want to add only `external_directory/SpecificFile1.scala`, `external_directory/SpecificFile2.scala`.

Or keep command `unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "external_directory"` **and** add command

```
sources in Compile --= Seq("ExcludedSpecificFile1.scala", "ExcludedSpecificFile2.scala")
  .map(baseDirectory.value / "external_directory" / _)
```

if you want to add everything from `external_directory` except `external_directory/ExcludedSpecificFile1.scala`, `external_directory/ExcludedSpecificFile2.scala`.